# how to read most recent partition in apache spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, natural-sort

I have a used the dataframe which contains the query

```
df : Dataframe =spark.sql(s"show Partitions $yourtablename")
```

Now the number of partition changes every day as it runs every day.

The main concern is that I need to fetch the latest partition.

Suppose I get the partition for a random table for a particular day
like

```
year=2019/month=1/day=1
year=2019/month=1/day=10
year=2019/month=1/day=2
year=2019/month=1/day=21
year=2019/month=1/day=22
year=2019/month=1/day=23
year=2019/month=1/day=24
year=2019/month=1/day=25
year=2019/month=1/day=26
year=2019/month=2/day=27
year=2019/month=2/day=3
```

Now you can see the functionality that it sorts the partition so that after `day=1` comes `day=10`. This creates a problem, as I need to fetch the latest partition.

I have managed to get the partition by using

```
val df =dff.orderby(col("partition").desc.limit(1)
```

but this gives me the tail -1 partition and not the latest partition.

How can I get the latest partition from the tables overcoming hives's limitation of arranging partitions?

So suppose in the above example I need to pick up

```
 year=2019/month=2/day=27
```

and not

```
year=2019/month=2/day=3
```

which is the last partition in the table.

Comment: I would read the partition with an appropriate query with s""" using predicate pushdown.

Answer (score 2):

You can get max partitions from `SHOW PARTITIONS`

```
spark.sql("SHOW PARTITIONS my_database.my_table").select(max('partition)).show(false)
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the case of HDFS or S3.

Comment: @ChrisIvan There are several ways to make it work. One example will be using `saveAsTable()`.

Comment: Not if your goal is to avoid a costly loading of all partitions in S3 just to find the most recent partition, that's exactly the problem I am trying to solve. I manage by using boto3 to find the most recent partition key via S3 API, and then hard-code it in a WHERE condition to make use of pushdown predicates. It's hackey, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I would no rely on positional dependency but if you were to do so I would at least have year=2019/month=2/day=**0**3.

I would rely on partition pruning and SQL via an SQL statement. I am not sure if you are using ORC, PARQUET, etc. but partition pruning should be a goer.

E.g.

```
 val df = sparkSession.sql(""" select max(partition_col)
                                 from randomtable 
                           """)

 val maxVal = df.first().getString(0) // this as sql result is a DF
```

See also https://mapr.com/blog/tips-and-best-practices-to-take-advantage-of-spark-2-x/

Comment: I think the effect of that would be to force spark to scan all files in order to determine the maximum partition date, which is quite slow in the case of a large number of files and partitions.